# How to only move values rather than formulas in my Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Backorder LIST
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Backorder LIST" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
}
```

I am having trouble finding a way to move only the values to COMPLETED sheet. Anytime I change `.moveTo(target);` to `.copyTo(target, {contentsOnly: true});` the script fails. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide debugging details, if you're looking for debugging help. `the script fails` isn't descriptive enough. See [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Move values only

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Backorder LIST" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed");
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Why would my previous one not work just out of curiosity and trying to learn.

Comment: I don't know.  It just seemed clumsy to me and I went immediately to replacing it.